# CSS Grid: every grid-row last column hover if span the grid-column if I wills space some issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

every row last column hover to add the **grid-column: span 2** and **grid-row: span 2**

I'm facing the issue of unstable the last column in hover.

Here is my code. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

```css
.Grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.Grid-Column {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.Grid-Column:hover {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> One </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Two </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Three </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Four </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Five </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Six </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Seven </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Eight </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Nine </h1> </div>
  <div class="Grid-Column"> <h1> Ten </h1> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen? Your question is not clear, sorry. I can see the problem - hovering over the rightmost grid cell in each row makes the cell bigger, so it won't fit in the row any more and it jumps to the next row - but what is the solution you need?

Comment: any other alternative concept?. columns  is  infinite and  hover to expand width 200% and height 200%